# Google Calendar: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes." when moving to calendar.readonly

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

Initially, I had the following scope:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
```

with the code:

```
credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    **flask.session['credentials'])
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
events_result =service.calendarList().list().execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

which worked well. However, as I don't require access to write/delete user calendar & to prevent user from getting

> See, edit, share and permanently delete all the calendars that you can access using Google Calendar

& to protect their safety, I narrowed my scope down to

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly']
```

with the same code. However, now I am getting:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

Even though the [doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#auth) mentions you're able to execute such code to retrieve events with both of the scopes.

Comment: Could you go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions and remove your app from the list then run your application again.  It should force a reset of the access your user had, and request that they authorize your application again.    If that doesnt work would you mind posting [example] i need to see your full code including the authorization code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script and scope, you are trying to retrieve the calendar list from `events_result =service.calendarList().list().execute()` with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

When you want to retrieve the calendar list using your current script, please modify the scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly`.

When you want to retrieve the event list, please modify your script as follows. In this case, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly` can be used.

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

- Please modify the calendar ID for your situation.

#### References:

- [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)
- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)